# Repository implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, repository

I have a repository called `PostsRepository`:

```
public class PostsRepository : IPostsRepository
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();

    public IEnumerable<Post> All()
    {
        return
            context.Posts
                   .OrderBy(post => post.PublishedAt);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Post> AllPublishedPosts()
    {
        return
            context.Posts
                   .OrderBy(post => post.PublishedAt)
                   .Where(post => !post.Draft);
    }

    public Post Find(string slug)
    {
        return context.Posts.Find(slug);
    }

    public void Create(Post post)
    {
        post.Slug = SlugConverter.Convert(post.Slug);
        post.Summary = Summarize(post.Content);
        post.PublishedAt = DateTime.Now;
        AttachTags(post);

        if (context.Posts.Find(post.Slug) != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("tag already exists. choose another.");
        }

        context.Posts.Add(post);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(Post post)
    {
        post.Slug = SlugConverter.Convert(post.Slug);
        post.Summary = Summarize(post.Content);
        AttachTags(post);

        if (context.Posts.Find(post.Slug) != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("tag already exists. choose another.");
        }

        context.Posts.Add(post);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(Post post)
    {
        context.Posts.Remove(post);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void AttachTags(Post post)
    {
        foreach (var tag in post.Tags)
        {
            if (context.Tags.Any(x => x.Name == tag.Name))
            {
                context.Tags.Attach(tag);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string Summarize(string content)
    {
        // contrived.
        return content;
    }
}
```

I am worried that I might have wound up with a design that is not very testable as it is not apparent to me *how* to test this code.

I am going to ask another question on SO as to how to unit test this class soon but before I peruse this implementation I would like to ask that you please review my repository implementation.

Particular areas of concern:

- Testability
- I have read countless opinions about what a repository should do. Are there any *pragmatic* reasons why my implementation might be bad?
- The `PostsRepository` needs to access the `Tags` database set. Am I allowing this in the correct way? Know that I plan to implement a `TagsRepository` in the future.
- I throw an exception when the slug (which must be unique) is occupied. Should I return a `bool` to indicate failure instead? Would this not violate the command-query segregation principle?
- I am aware that the `Update` method is hard to reason about and I am working on that. It is for this reason that my code does not currently adhere to DRY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Testability

Your repository implements an interface which will allow it to get stubbed out easily, so that's a very testable thing. However if you want to also (unit-test) your repositories themselves then you are stuck because you have a hardcoded dependency on `DatabaseContext`.

You should move that up one layer by abstracting it out as well and providing a custom `DbContext` for testing purposes or by mocking it out. More information on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463017/unit-testing-with-ef4-code-first-and-repository).

> I have read countless opinions about what a repository should do. Are there any pragmatic reasons why my implementation might be bad?

One thing that comes to mind is the long-lived `DbContext` object. Some say [it isn't an exact necessity](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U-Hxnfl_sn0), others say [you definitely should avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663754/entity-framework-4-lifespan-scope-of-context-in-a-winform-application) but generally accepted is the notion that you should dispose of your `DbContext`. A *unit of work* corresponds to one method inside your repository to wrap a `using` statement around it.

Note that this would interfere with testing the repository itself so it's worth considering using integration-tests to test your repository in particular.

> The `PostsRepository` needs to access the `Tags` database set. Am I allowing this in the correct way? Know that I plan to implement a `TagsRepository` in the future.

I am not familiar enough with EF to answer that.

> I throw an exception when the slug (which must be unique) is occupied. Should I return a `bool` to indicate failure instead? Would this not violate the command-query segregation principle?

It does not violate it because it is just the result of your command, it is not the result of a query. It holds exactly the same value as an exception.

There is a more interesting way though: create a "result"-object. This can be as simple as

```
class CallResult {
    bool Success { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Which will be more descriptive than `bool` since you can also send a message along. Whether you choose this or an exception depends on your own preference: using an exception will force you to have a try-catch around it somewhere which is rather ugly but then again it will prevent you from accidentally leaving out validation on the return type (either a `try-catch` or `if(result.Success)`) which is not enforced with a custom type.

> I am aware that the `Edit` method is hard to reason about and I am working on that. It is for this reason that my code does not currently adhere to DRY.

Since I don't see an `Edit` method I'll assume you haven't written it yet. DRY is nice and all but for some niche situations (CRUD actions, tests, ..) I would argue that readability is more important than having a few lines similar to eachother.

I suppose you could create a situation like this, but that depends on how different each action is.

```
void Process(Post post) {
    post.Slug = SlugConverter.Convert(post.Slug);

    if (context.Posts.Find(post.Slug) != null)
    {
        throw new Exception("tag already exists. choose another.");
    }

    post.Summary = Summarize(post.Content);
    AttachTags(post);
}

void Create(Post post) {
    Process(post);
    post.PublishedAt = DateTime.Now;
    context.Posts.Add(post);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

void Update(Post post) {
    Process(post);
    context.Posts.Add(post);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note how I performed the validation *before* doing the other work.

---

A method should be written as *[action][context]*. `AllPublishedPosts` makes me think it's a property, not a method. I would change this to `GetAllPublishedPosts`. I'm not speaking out about `All` since that's a special situation, I suppose.

Comment: You make some good points. I completely forgot to give consideration to the lifetime of the database context for example. And my apologies. I meant to say that the `Update` method is hard to reason about - there is no method called `Edit`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. One thing I noticed is that you have a fair amount of code duplication. It's something I try to avoid because it means if you find a problem in a piece of code which is duplicated then you have to go and them all and fix them. If you just have one place where you perform a certain operation then there is only one place to fix/extend.

   Some examples:

   - Shared code between `All` and `AllPublishedPosts`. Can be refactored into:

     ```
     public IEnumerable<Post> All()
     {
         return context.Posts.OrderBy(post => post.PublishedAt);
     }

     public IEnumerable<Post> AllPublishedPosts()
     {
         return All().Where(post => !post.Draft);
     }
     ```
   - `Create` and `Update` are pretty much exactly the same method except for a single line. I'd refactor it into:

     ```
     public void Create(Post post)
     {
         CreateOrUpdate(post, true);
     }

     public void Update(Post post)
     {
         CreateOrUpdate(post, false);
     }

     private void CreateOrUpdate(Post post, bool isNewPost)
     {
         post.Slug = SlugConverter.Convert(post.Slug);
         post.Summary = Summarize(post.Content);
         if (isNewPost)
         {
             post.PublishedAt = DateTime.Now;
         }
         AttachTags(post);

         if (context.Posts.Find(post.Slug) != null)
         {
             throw new Exception("tag already exists. choose another.");
         }

         context.Posts.Add(post);
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
     ```
   - You already have a `Find` method but you duplicate the code in `Create` and `Update`. Use `Find` there instead.
2. Avoid throwing generic `Exception` - be specific. In `Create` and `Update` it would probably make more sense to throw an `ArgumentException`.
3. You should try to bail early. Right now in `Create` and `Update` you perform a bunch of operations just to potentially reject the post later. Something like this would seem to make more sense:

   ```
       private void CreateOrUpdate(Post post, bool isNewPost)
       {
           post.Slug = SlugConverter.Convert(post.Slug);
           if (Find(post.Slug) != null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentException("tag already exists. choose another.");
           }

           post.Summary = Summarize(post.Content);
           if (isNewPost)
           {
               post.PublishedAt = DateTime.Now;
           }
           AttachTags(post);
           context.Posts.Add(post);
           context.SaveChanges();
       }
   ```
4. `DatabaseContext` should probably be an interface so you can inject it through the repository constructor. For unit testing you can mock out the interface. If the repository is a transient entity (i.e. constructed per web-request for example) then injecting the context through the constructor is probably the most straight forward way. If the repository is longer lived (like a singleton lifestyle) then you might want to consider the [unit of work pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) in order to limit the lifetime of your context.